# C++ constructor issues

Tags: c++, constructor, rvalue, most-vexing-parse

I wonder if anybody can help with what seems to me like strange behaviour in `c++` (`gcc` latest version). Below is some code that compiles successfully where I would expect a compile time error due to the lack of an appropriate constructor. Can anybody explain what is going on?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ClassA {
  ClassA() {cout << "hello" << endl;} 
  void speak() {cout << "I am class A" << endl;}
  ~ClassA() {cout << "goodbye" << endl;} 
};

struct ClassB {
    // just an empty struct
};

int main() {
    ClassA myClassA(ClassB()); // trying to construct class A from an rvalue reference to class B is ok?
    return 0;
}
```

}

If I try to call a function of `class A`, I do get a compile time error:

```
int main() {
    ClassA myClassA(ClassB());
    myClassA.speak();
    return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
error: request for member ‘speak’ in ‘myClassA', which is of non-class type ‘ClassA(ClassB (*)())’
```

Thanks!

Comment: @AndyProwl, It is indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never declaring an object at all. Instead, you've declared a *function*, and so there's no constructor needed at all. (Note that `ClassB()` denotes a function type!)

If you want to construct an object from a temporary, try one of these syntaxes:

```
ClassA x1 { ClassB{} };   // C++11 only

ClassA x2((ClassB()));    // parenthesized expression is never a type declaration
```

Comment: @pstrjds: I think it's just an ordinary vexing parse. The most-vexing one is a bit more involved yet.

Comment: Oh! I've never even seen those syntaxes before. Thanks for that!

Comment: @KerrekSB - Figured it was close enough for a reference

Comment: An ordinary vexing parse would be `ClassA myClassA();`. This is the most vexing parse.

Comment: Many thanks for the help all who answered. I love c++, it's so baffling!

Answer (score 1):

`ClassA myClassA(ClassB());` declares a *function* called `myClassA` that returns a `ClassA` and takes one argument which is a pointer to a function that returns a `ClassB` and takes no arguments. This is the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation called the Most Vexing Parse.

First and formost, `ClassB` *does* have a constructor. When you don't create one of your own the compiler provides one for you. And on the line where you passed an instance of `ClassB` into what seems like a valid copy construction, what actually happens is that the line is evaluated as the declaration of a function that returns an instance of `ClassA` and takes an anonymous instance of `ClassB`.